# nextJs set Image to auto height

Tags: reactjs, next.js, height, nextjs-image

My problem with Image component from Next.js

I receiving from api urls to images with different resolution.

imageContainer have width to 100% and I want to force the images to take the necessary height auto.

For the moment I use this solution:https://dev.to/tanahmed/next-image-make-image-fill-available-space-272o

However, I believe that this is not the correct approach because it is not the solution envisaged by the nextJS developers

I have searched for a solution but most solutions force you to know the width and height which I do not know.

I am also not able to specify the height of the container permanently, it must be automatic

Fill property is not a solution because i do not know height of container.

Comment: I'm facing the same problem. Surprised that nobody is talking about this. This should be addressed in the official docs.